# How do I transform multiple columns to a stacked column set of three in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, report, transform

I have data (see image one)  of twelve months columned by Date-Jan, Day, Hours,/ Date-Feb, Day, Hours,/etc... for a total of 36 columns.

[image: Data]

I am trying to transform that sheet into a new sheet report style and its should look stacked (see image 2)  it should have four columns by Name (of the employee), Date, Day, Hours.

[image: report style]

**Few things to Note:**

It has to be a **reference** - so when I change the hours in sheet1 in *automatically updates* in sheet2. NO COPY PASTE. (so like example(=b2)) (no need to be reversed) .

If I try to reiterate by every three columns, keep in mind that every month has a *different amount of days* and we don't want empty rows.

I was thinking of vlookup or the index function, but cant seem to make it work

Comment: There won't be a neat solution with this design: In D2 write ̀ =E6` and pull it down until `4/30/2021` then write into  the cell below `=H6` and pull it down until `5/31/2021`. And so on for the other months.

Comment: The years and months vary from sheet to sheet, so it needs to be dynamic and figure out how many days in the month.

Comment: Fastest way is probably copy each month and then "paste link" on the report sheet.  You'd need VBA if you want it automated - you could try copying a few blocks while recording a macro, and use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Developping a single dynamic formula reference (MS 365)**

> *"It has to be a reference - so when I change the hours in sheet1 in automatically updates in sheet2"*

The pre-determined fixed structure lets you a **way out** to
get the wanted dynamic reference. The *"escape route"* is simply to

- **recalculate** the date values (col 2-Date and 3-Day) as numeric sequence by a formula *instead* of trying to refer to the *original dates*,
- and to include all needed column results as first step in something like

```
   =CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},Employee,dt,dt,hours)
```

As following step you need to enclose all needed column parameters into sort of a formula container (`LET()`) defining all column inputs,
partially by reference to **named cells**, which could be for example

- `Employee`  .. e.g. `"Bob Smith"`)
- `StartDate` .. e.g. 4/1 2021 (equalling here `44291`)
- `StartYear` .. e.g. 2021
- `StartMonth`.. e.g. 4

The `LET` function (available in MS 365) allows to do this in a
structured way avoiding some redundancies as well.

```
    =LET(data,Sheet1!$C$6:$AL$36,dt,SEQUENCE(366,1,StartDate),hours,INDEX(data,DAY(dt),(MONTH(dt)+(YEAR(dt)-StartYear)*12-StartMonth)*3+3),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},Employee,dt,dt,hours))
```

By entering this formula into any target cell (e.g. in `Sheet2`) you get a dynamic **spill range** of four columns
with automatic display of changes of original hours.

Hint: I leave it to you to refine the `Let` formula considering *leap years*, too.

To get eventually the right **report layout** for the calculated date sequences (just numbers), you have to format the 2nd and 3rd output columns with the wanted date formats,
e.g. `"'m\/d"` and `"[$-409]ddd"`.

**Overview of formula parts**

which includes line feeds for better readibility

```
 =LET(
      data,  Sheet1!$C$6:$AL$36,
      dt,    SEQUENCE(366,1,StartDate),
      hours, INDEX(data,DAY(dt),(MONTH(dt)+(YEAR(dt)-StartYear)*12-StartMonth)*3+3),
      CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},Employee,dt,dt,hours)
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

As @PEH mentioned correctly in comment, there's no *"neat solution"* regarding changing month lengths **and** your requirement *"It has to be a reference - so when I change the hours in sheet1 in automatically updates in sheet2"*

**VBA Run-up without direct references**

*(c.f. ►2nd post developping a single dynamic formula reference)*

Due to the **fixed structure** of your range of 31 x 36 data cells, you could, however

- provide for a
  report array with 31*12 *rows* and 4 *columns* *(Name,Date,Day,Hours)* ,
- that you fill with the employee's name (col.1),
  with *calculated* **dates** (assumed: strings!) ranging from 1 to max. 31 days (col. 2 & 3),
  as well as the **hours** read in column-wise from source
- and write back to any wanted target.

**Example call**

Change worksheet indications following your needs.

```
Sub WriteReport()
'A) create report
    Dim report As Variant
    report = getReport("Bob Smith", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
'B) write report to any wanted target
    With Sheet2            
    .Range("A1".resize(1,4) = split("Name,Date,Day,Hours", ",")
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(report), UBound(report, 2)) = report
    End With
End Sub
```

**Help function `getReport()`**

```
Function getReport(ByVal employee As String, _
     SourceSheet As Worksheet, _
     Optional StartYear As Long = 2021, _
     Optional startMonth As Long = 4)
'0) get start dates for e.g. 12 months via  help function getDates()
    Const MonthsCount As Long = 12
    Dim datearr: datearr = getDates(DateSerial(StartYear, startMonth, 1), MonthsCount)
'1) define source range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = SourceSheet.Range("A6").Resize(31, 3 * MonthsCount)
'2) define 1-based 2-dim report array comprising 31 x 4 elements
    Dim report
    ReDim report(1 To MonthsCount * 31, 1 To 4)
'3) add calculated dates and add monthly hours to report array
    Dim mth As Long, d As Long, cnt As Long
    For mth = 1 To MonthsCount
        'get monthly hours as 2-dim array (1 column each)
        Dim monthlyHours: monthlyHours = rng.Columns(mth * 3 + 2).Value
        For d = 1 To ultimo(datearr(mth))
            cnt = cnt + 1
            report(cnt, 1) = employee
            report(cnt, 2) = Application.Text(datearr(mth) + d - 1, "'m\/d")      ' force date string
            report(cnt, 3) = Application.Text(datearr(mth) + d - 1, "[$-409]ddd") ' force EN-US vers.
            report(cnt, 4) = monthlyHours(d, 1)
        Next d
    Next
'4) return function result
    getReport = report
End Function
```

**Help function `getDates()`**

Returns a 1-dim array of the starting date for each month

```
Function getDates(dt As Date, Optional MonthsCount As Long = 12)
'Purpose: get 1-dim array of last 12 months dates 
'a) get start date
    Dim EndDate As Date: EndDate = DateAdd("m", MonthsCount, dt)
    Dim yrs As Long:     yrs = Year(EndDate) - Year(dt)
'b) get column numbers representing a months sequence
    Dim cols As String
    cols = Split(Cells(, Month(dt)).Address, "$")(1)
    cols = cols & ":" & Split(Cells(, Month(EndDate) - 1 + Abs(yrs * 12)).Address, "$")(1)
'c) evaluate dates
    getDates = Evaluate("Date(" & Year(dt) & _
        ",Column(" & cols & "),1)")
End Function
```

**Help function `ultimo()`**

Calculates the last day of a given month date (ranging from 28 to 31).
This is possible using zero (`0`) as theoretical day input and last argument in function `getSerial()`
if applied for the next month (month + 1) .

```
Function ultimo(ByVal dt) As Long
'Purp.: return last day of month
        ultimo = Day(DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) + 1, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: Note the OP needs formulas in the report (*"It has to be a reference - so when I change the hours in sheet1 in automatically updates in sheet2"*).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, of course this changes the game.  @PEH

Comment: Yea, that is actually why I commented that  there will not be a *"neat solution"* for that if you actually have to link those cells, and month positions can change (according OP) that's a mess. I mean if we redesign the original sheet there might be a solution (I made similar things) but that's too far away to give a good answer).

Comment: ... and without knowing OP's actual logic how to procede. Thx again. - Nevertheless, I'll leave my answer as alternative demonstrating some useful methods. @PEH

Comment: Fyi Posted a MS 365 way-out showing all needed columns at once in a spill range, when recalculating dates in the `LET` formula instead of referring to the original data. - Appreciated valuable feedback @PEH

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this formula and it worked.

```
firstDate = DateValue("4/1/2021")
secondDate = DateValue("4/1/2024")
n = DateDiff("d", firstDate, secondDate)
sc = Sheets.Count
scd = sc - 3
datar = "$A$1:$G$" & scd * n + 1


For c = sc - 1 To 3 Step -1
    q = Sheets(c).Name
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula2R1C1 = "=SEQUENCE(DAYS(""4/1/2024"",""4/1/2021""),,""4/1/2021"")"
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(n).Formula2R1C1 = "=TEXT(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0),""ddd"")"
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(n).Formula2R1C1 = Sheets(c).Range("$K$1")
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-n + 1, 0).Resize(n).Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & q & "'" & "!$A$1"
    Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(n).Formula2R1C1 = "=INDEX(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38,IF(LARGE((" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38=RC2)*ROW(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38),1),LARGE((" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38=RC2)*ROW(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38),1)-5,""""),IFERROR(MATCH(RC2,INDEX(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38,IF(LARGE((" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38=RC2)*ROW(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38),1),LARGE((" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38=RC2)*ROW(" & q & "!R6C3:R114C38),1)-5,""""),0),0),"""")+2)"
```